# Kotlin. Runtime error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: kotlin

I have a task in JetBrains Academy:
"Write a program that reads an unsorted list of integers and two numbers: P and M. The program needs to check whether P and M occur in the list.

The first line contains the size of the list.
The next N lines contain the elements of the list.
The last line contains two integer numbers P and M separated by a space.

If both numbers occur in the list you need to print YES, otherwise – NO."

My code:

```
fun main() {
    val size = readln().toInt()
    val mutList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
    val (a, b) = readln().split(" ")
    val p: Int = a.toInt()
    val m: Int = b.toInt()
    

    for (i in 0 until size) {
        mutList.add(readln().toInt())
    }
    
    if(p in mutList || m in mutList) {
        print("YES")
    } else {
        print("NO")
    }

}
```

And I have this error:

```
Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonList.get(Collections.java:4849)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:4)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:198)
```

I'm newbie at Kotlin and coding at all, but I keep trying to learn some. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the question, you need to input the list elements before P and M. Also, you have to print "YES" when both numbers occur in list i.e. you need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val size = readln().toInt()
    val list = List(size) { readln().toInt() }
    val (p, m) = readln().split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
        
    if(p in list && m in list) {
        println("YES")
    } else {
        println("NO")
    }
}
```